# Death and revival of land-creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I have a question regarding MTG rules and how can be applied. In this case, it's about lands that can become creatures. I was checking [this one-mana EDH deck](http://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/one-drop-edh/), and I saw that the Commander has this ability:

> [Horde of Notions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHorde%20of%20Notions%5d) {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}
>
> Legendary Creature — Elemental (5/5)
>
> Vigilance, trample, haste
>
> {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}: You may play target Elemental card from your
>   graveyard without paying its mana cost.
>
> *Even the oldest treefolk was but an acorn when Lorwyn’s first*
>   *mysteries were born.*

I was wondering: if the land was killed and sent to the graveyard **while being a creature** by any X reason (say "Lightning bolt"), is it possible to retrieve it back using this ability? For example, [Celestial Colonnade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCelestial%20Colonnade%5d) can turn into an Elemental until end of turn.

Comment: Please do not include deck lists in questions like this. They're simply not relevant. You can instead refer to a specific cards that are relevant to your question. The edit I've made to your question shows what I mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Horde of Notions cannot do anything with a land card that died as a creature. The key rule is [rule 400.7](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Zone):

> An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

If a land card like Celestial Colonnade dies as a creature, the effect that made it a creature doesn't continue to apply to the card in the graveyard. While it's in the graveyard, it's just a land card.